# Problem with changing values of State Hook which is an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I have rather simple problem.

I don't know why my useState function won't change state -> `props`

```js
onChangeText={(text) => {
  setProps({ ...props, inputValue: text });
}}
```

I declared my state as here:

```js
const [props, setProps] = useState({
  pageNumber: 2,
  inputValue: "",
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't any problem with your code. your input element should look like this:  `<input  onChange={(e)=> onChangeText(e.target.value)}/>` that way you state will be updated.

Comment: Why do you think that the state update isn't working? Add more details.

Comment: @RameshReddy I just updated my comment

Comment: @IsiakaLukmanBamidele My comment was for Adam

Comment: Adam, what is the content of `text` when you log it? Usually `onChange` callbacks return an object and not a string, so you might have to do something like `text.target.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prevState` received by the updater function is guaranteed to be up-to-date. It's a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. [Official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

```
onChange={(event) => {
    setProps(prevState => {
       return { ...prevState, inputValue: event.target.value }
    });
}}
```

Also if you have `input` just use native event `onChange` instead of custom `onChangeText`

Comment: the functional update is definitely better but let OP confirm the issue

Answer (score -1):

You wrote '`onChangeText`' instead of '`onChange`'. And, it gives you the event object rather than the text itself. It should be like this:

```js
    <input onChange={(event) => {
        setProps({ ...props, inputValue: event.target.value });
      }} />
```

Comment: Why did you assume that `onChangeText` is used as a prop to an input element?

Comment: @RameshReddy I don't see another context possible... I tried it myself and that was the only thing that didn't work in his example. He didn't give any context, so how should I know?...

Comment: Exactly, You shouldn't assume the context and answer. Wait until the question is answerable.

Answer (score -1):

What you doing is correct and nothing is wrong with it.

you need to pass your state value to the input

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const initialState = {
    pageNumber: 2,
    inputValue: ""
  };

  const [props, setProps] = useState(initialState);

  const textInputChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setProps({ ...props, inputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={props.inputValue}
        type="text"
        onChange={textInputChangeHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```